# Neo4j how can I merge two nodes in Java?

Tags: merge, neo4j, nodes

Any fast ways to merge two nodes into one, without traverse the properties and relatioships myself?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement that yourself - including conflict resolution if e.g. both nodes contains the same property with different values etc.

Neo4j does not offer any support for this (since this is probably not a very common use case).